# Setting latest start time to nodes in Directed Acyclic Graph

Tags: java, graph-theory, depth-first-search, directed-acyclic-graphs

I've made a DAG consisting of objects of class Node. Every node knows its own earliest start time, earliest finish time, and also its own time. Every node also has a `List<Task> innNodes` and a `List<Task> outNodes`.

What I have done so far is sorting using topological sort.

How can I set the latest start time for every node in this graph?

I tried doing what I did when setting `earliest start time`, which was a Depth First Search starting from the root-node, only this time doing it in reverse by starting from the last node.

[Drawn picture of my Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NS1FR.png) (Edit: 2 -> 7)

What I tried to do:

```
/*
*@param maxLen is the earliest finish time of the last node
*/
private void setLatest(Node root, Node last, int maxLen){
    int latest = maxLen;
    latest -= last.getTime();
    last.latestStart = latest;
    for(Node n : last.getInnNodes()){
        if (n.latestStart == 0){
            if(n == root){
                continue;
            }
            n.latestStart = latest;
            setLatest(root, n, latest);
        }
     }
}
```

Edit: also tried this, still dosn't work

```
//cntNext is 2 for root, and 0 for leafs
public void setLatest(){
    Stack<Node> stack = new Stack<Node>();
    List<Node> list = new ArrayList<Node>(sorted);
    int rootTime = getRoot().earliestStart;
    for(Node n : leafs){
        n.latestStart = leafTime;
        stack.push(n);
    }
    while(!stack.isEmpty()){
        Node n = stack.pop();
        int time = n.latestStart;
        for (Node v : n.getInnNodes()){
            list.remove(v);
            v.cntNext--;
            if(v.cntNext == 0){
                time -= v.getTime();
                v.latestStart = time;
                stack.push(v);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

This output:

```
ID: 5    Earliest Start: 0    Latest Start: 0   (Expected 0)
ID: 6    Earliest Start: 4    Latest Start: 12  (Expected 12)
ID: 1    Earliest Start: 4    Latest Start: 13  (Expected 4)
ID: 2    Earliest Start: 8    Latest Start: 11  (Expected 8)
ID: 4    Earliest Start: 14   Latest Start: 0   (Expected 14)
ID: 3    Earliest Start: 14   Latest Start: 17  (Expected 14)
ID: 7    Earliest Start: 14   Latest Start: 14  (Expected 14)
ID: 8    Earliest Start: 18   Latest Start: 18  (Expected 18)
```

Answer (score 1):

For those curious this worked:

```
/* Reverse topological sort using stack */

public void setLatestStart(){
    int critical = earliestProjectFinishTime;
    int time = critical;
    HashSet<Node> S = new HashSet<Node>();

    for(Node n : leafs){                            /* set latest start time of all leaves to critical, as no node depend on them */
        n.latestStart = time - n.getTime();
        S.add(n);
    }

    while(!S.isEmpty()){
        Node n = S.iterator().next();
        S.remove(n);
        time = n.latestStart;
        for(Node m : n.getInnNodes()){
            if(m.latestStart > time || m.latestStart == 0){             /* this protects the node from being overwritten by non-critical nodes */
                m.latestStart = time - m.getTime();
                S.add(m);
            }
        }
    }
    for(Node n : roots){
        n.latestStart = 0;
    }
}
```